# How to update the state with the latest fetched item with an interval callback function inside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm quite new to the React-TS world and I have recently been playing with `useState` and `useEffect` hooks only basically.

I have the following functional component inside which I'd like to fetch N items the first time and then start a periodic function that fetches the last item from the response data, updating the current state.

```js
const fetcher = async (url: string) => await axios.get(url).then((res: AxiosResponse) => res.data);

type AirflowData = {
  value: number; // perc values from 0 to 1
  timestamp: number; // UTC time
};

const ActionDetector: React.FC = () => {
  const [alerts, setAlerts] = useState<AirflowData[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch the latest N alerts first
    getAlerts(100);
    // Then start fetching the last alert every N milliseconds
    const interval = setInterval(() => getLatestAlert(), 1000);

    // Clear interval
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  /**
   * Return the alert data after fetching it.
   * @param numAlerts number of the last N alerts to return
   */
  const getAlerts = async (numAlerts: number) => {
    const fetchedAlerts: AirflowData[] = await fetcher("http://localhost:9500/alerts");
    setAlerts(fetchedAlerts.slice(-numAlerts));
  };
  /**
   * Return the latest alert data available.
   */
  const getLatestAlert = async () => {
    const fetchedAlerts: AirflowData[] = await fetcher("http://localhost:9500/alerts");
    const latestFetchedAlert = fetchedAlerts.slice(-1)[0];
    const latestAlert = alerts.slice(-1)[0];

    if (latestFetchedAlert && latestAlert && latestFetchedAlert.timestamp !== latestAlert.timestamp) {
      // Append the alert only if different from the previous one
      setAlerts([...alerts, latestFetchedAlert]);
    }
  };

  console.log(alerts);

  return <></>
}

export default ActionDetector
```

The problem with this approach is that `latestAlert` is always `undefined` and that is due, if I understood how React works under the hood correctly, to the initial state change re-rendering trigger. After `getAlerts()` is called and fires `setAlerts(...)`, the component starts the re-rendering and so, since `getLatestAlert()` is called inside the `useEffect` only the first time (the first render), it always read `alerts` as the initialized empty array.

I don't know if this is the correct reason behind this, but how can I achieve what I'm trying to do the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental issue is that when updating state based on existing state, you need to be sure you have the latest state information. Your `getLatestAlerts` function closes over the `alerts` constant that was in scope when it was created, so it only ever uses that version of the constant (not the updated one from a subsequent render). Your `useEffect` `setInterval` callback closes over the `getLatestAlerts` function that was in scope when *it* was created, and only ever uses that version of the function.

To be sure you have the latest state, use the callback version of the state setter instead of the constant:

```
const getLatestAlert = async () => {
    const fetchedAlerts: AirflowData[] = await fetcher("http://localhost:9500/alerts");
    const latestFetchedAlert = fetchedAlerts.slice(-1)[0];
    if (latestFetchedAlert) {
        setAlerts(alerts => {
            const latestAlert = alerts.slice(-1)[0];

            if (latestFetchedAlert && latestAlert && latestFetchedAlert.timestamp !== latestAlert.timestamp) {
                // Append the alert only if different from the previous one
                alerts = [...alerts, latestFetchedAlert];
            }
            return alerts;
        });
    }
};
```

---

Purely as a side note, I wouldn't use the idiom you seem to be using to get the last item from an array, `array.slice(-1)[0]`. Instead, I'd either use `array[array.length - 1]`, or use the [`at` method](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-relative-indexing-method) which *just* achieved Stage 4 and will be in this year's spec (it's easily polyfilled for older environments).

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue indeed. I didn't catch from the documentation that alternative use of `useState` sadly. Thanks for the headsup on the last item idiom aswell. As a note, I think that instead of calling `setAlerts` again I need to do a `return [...alerts, latestFetchedAlert]` inside the last `if` and `return alerts` outside it to make it work. Since the callback version expect a return value (`(prevState: AirflowData[]) => AirflowData[]`). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Barnercart - **Doh!** Yes, you're right, I've fixed the answer. Sorry about that. :-)